# Get Google Drive token

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api

We have issue about upload file to google drive, it is a service, when user put something in our "WatchFolder", our service will automatic upload file to google drive, we hope user login google account in ASP web page, get token, and then service use that token upload file, but the service is C#, do anyone have way to do that kind of things?

Comment: Take a look at their developer documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: @Nkosi I already check that, it is looks work for ASP.Net application, not for asp